# When are navigational properties loaded?

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-4.0

If an entity A has a FK relationship with entity B, and is represented as a navigational property in entity A inside EF4, when are data from entity B loaded? Is it upon creating an instance of A, or only when B is accessed from within A?

Comment: Depends on type of loading used. Check [this article](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/maximizing-performance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application) showing the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on loading method:

- Eager loading - the query loading A contains `.Include(a => a.B)`. In such case both A and related Bs are loaded during query execution
- Lazy loading - only A is loaded during the first query and if it is still in scope of living context it can trigger lazy loading of B once navigation property accessed first time
- Explicit loading - you will manually trigger loading by calling `context.LoadProperty(a, "B");`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to look into [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx), perhaps you're more interested in eager loading.